# AngularJS GET request returning 404, though its accessible

Tags: angularjs, spring

Firing AngularJS Rest URL as a GET request from AngularJS, its 
 returning 404 though its hitting the required method on server 
 side (spring implementaiton) and producing the desired Result

Could somebody tell me what could be the problem ?

Below is the method firing the angularjs request

```
 getCredentials : function(){
             return $http.get('/helloRest/getUsername');
 }
```

The above method results in the

```
   URL : http://localhost:8083/helloRest/getUsername
```

below is the stack traces

```
 <body>
 <h1>HTTP Status 404 - /helloRest/getUsername</h1>
 <div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p>
 <b>message</b> 
 <u>/helloRest/getUsername</u></p><p>
 <b>description</b> 
 <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p>
 <hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.37</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: The problem is on the server, not the client. Show us why you think this should not cause a 404.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/getUsername",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public void authenticateUser(HttpServletRequest hreq){
  System.out.println("credentials are");
  String principalObject = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
  
  System.out.println("security"+principalObject.toString());
  //return principalObject;
    
 }    //  This is the method I am hitting with URL , The entire method is executing and I could see the result, This is why I am expecting 200 but not 404...........  @Nizet thanks for responding

Comment: That is unreadable. Edit your question, and post all the relevant information: Spring config, context path of your webapp, code.

Comment: myserver is tomcat

Comment: creating a new question for this as need to show large amounts of code the comment section is not accepting it